# How do I find the newest matching record in MySQL when all of my search criteria can be null?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the nullable fields that I use as search criteria, and a `creation_date` for sorting by.

I'm trying to write a query to find the newest record based on those search criteria,  but if one of them is missing I'd like to still match it.

So I tried doing `fieldname = ? or null` for each field and used `order by creation_date limit 1`,  but if I do this then if there were a row where all of the fields were `null`, it would return that one instead of an older record where they are not all `null`.

How can I make it prefer results with more matching fields, but not require that every field exists?

Comment: Post representative sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like the following:

```
SELECT
   {field list}
FROM
   {your table}
WHERE
   IFNULL(field1, @par1) = @par1
   AND IFNULL(field2, @par2) = @par2
   .....
ORDER BY
   creation_date DESC 
limit 1
```

In the above case if i.e. `field1` had a NULL value for a particular record, `IFNULL` function would return the second parameter given, so the real comparison in that case would be `@par1 = @par1` which is always-true. Thus in case of NULL-valued field, the part doesn't affect the search results.

I hope it helps some way.